# ParserError: expected ',' but got identifier receive()

Tags: solidity

I state that I'm a solidity rookie.
Btw the compiler give me error "24:46:ParserError: expected ',' but got identifier receive().." and I can't understand where I should put the ",". Thanks for your help.[image]

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract ReavealMeASecret{
  address payable public whoNeed;
  string secret= "blabla";
  bool payment;

  event Reveal(uint _amount);

  constructor () public {
      whoNeed = msg.sender;
      payment = false;
  }

  modifier OnlyIfWhoNeed (address _whoNeed){
      require (msg.sender == _whoNeed, "Non ti è dato saperlo");
      _;
  }
  modifier Amount(uint _amount){
      require (msg.value >= _amount, "Se il segreto vuoi sapere, il soldo giusto devi avere");
      _;
  }

  receive() external payable OnlyIfWhoNeed Amount(2 Ether){
      owner.transfer (msg.value);
      payment = true;
      emit Reveal(msg.value);
  }
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The error is cause because `Ether` is not a keyword. You need to lowercase it, so it should be changed to `2 ether`, else Solidity does not recognise it as a keyword and tries to apply a different parsing flow.

See https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/units-and-global-variables.html#ether-units

I see 2 more errors in your code:

1. `OnlyIfWhoNeed` takes a parameter which is not provided
2. `owner` is not defined